# Missing characters in gnuplot generated eps while compiling pdf

Tags: xetex, eps, gnuplot

tTis has bug me for a few days: when I import a gnuplot generated `eps` into my LaTeX file, the characters are always missing. The number and text with in the figure is not complete, for example, it should show "sin(x)" but shows "s_**", should be "10000" but "1__**". Here "___" are blank spaces.

I am using Mac OSX 10.8.2, with TeX Live and `texlive-latex-extra` installed from Macports:

```
sudo port install texlive
sudo port install texlive-latex-extra
```

This is really a problem for me, can anyone help?

Comment: with a simple test, I think there is something wrong with the font. If I plot the eps file with Helvetica, then it has this problem.

Comment: Without a full demo we can't help here: we'd need to have a link to the EPS file, for example.